# Then is not a function error in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have simple function which returns employee data. But getting then is not a function error how to retrieve response from function

```
   function getdata(criteria) {
            return angularService.GetData(criteria, $scope.year, $scope.selectedYearType.name);
        }
```

Which is called in below function

```
$scope.GetEmployeeData = function (criteria) {

        $scope.searchMethod = getdata;
        $scope.searchMethod().then(function (response) {----------> Error here

           var totalEmployeeAmount = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < response.data.results.length; i++) {
                var summaryData = response.data.results[i];
                totalEmployeeAmount += (summaryData.totalEmployeeAmount);
            }


            return response

        }, function (response) {
            // This is to see if has any error 
            //console.log(response);

        });
    }
```

My angular service

```
function getData(criteria, year, yearType) {
            var url = apiService.ApiUrl + "/Employees/EmployeeHistory/GetData/" + year + "/" + yearType;
            return apiService.DeferredPost(url, criteria);}
```

Deferred Post Method

```
function deferredPost(url, params) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.post(url, params)
                .then(function (data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }, function (resp) {
                    deferred.reject(resp);
                }).catch(function (data) {
                    deferred.reject(data);
                });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

API

```
var api = {

            DeferredPost: deferredPost
        };
        return api;
```

Comment: show the `angularService.GetData` method

Comment: Assuming `angularService.GetData(...args)` returns a `Promise`. You should be using `$scope.searchMethod.then(function ... )` instead of `$scope.searchMethod().then(function ... )`

Comment: Can you post the full code of your angular service?

Answer (score 0):

Should be calling .then on searchMethod instead of searchMethod() - assuming getdata returns a promise as you can't call .then on a function that doesn't return a promise. Also I'm guessing you should be passing in the criteria as a parameter to getdata:

```
$scope.GetEmployeeData = function (criteria) {

        $scope.searchMethod = getdata;
        $scope.searchMethod.then(function (response) {

           var totalEmployeeAmount = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < response.data.results.length; i++) {
                var summaryData = response.data.results[i];
                totalEmployeeAmount += (summaryData.totalEmployeeAmount);
            }


            return response

        }, function (response) {
            // This is to see if has any error 
            //console.log(response);

        });
    }
```

Comment: if i pass criteria to getData its getting me null. and this is not returning any response

Comment: If you don't pass criteria to it, what happens?

Comment: If i don't pass then criteria in my web api is not null , it has data.

Comment: Did using $scope.searchMethod.then instead of $scope.searchMethod().then fix the issue?

Comment: What error are you getting now? What does your angularService.GetData function look like?

Comment: updated question to show how angular service looks like

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147941/discussion-between-william-hampshire-and-user1030181).

Answer (score 0):

As @William Hampshire said, you should be using `$scope.searchMethod.then(function ... )` instead of `$scope.searchMethod().then(function ... )`

```
$scope.GetEmployeeData = function (criteria) {

        $scope.searchMethod = getdata(criteria);
        $scope.searchMethod.then(function (response) {

           var totalEmployeeAmount = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < response.data.results.length; i++) {
                var summaryData = response.data.results[i];
                totalEmployeeAmount += (summaryData.totalEmployeeAmount);
            }


            return response

        }, function (response) {
            // This is to see if has any error 
            //console.log(response);

        });
    }
```

The reason why your code is still failing is that you have a typo in your service name.

```
   function getdata(criteria) {
            return angularService.GetData(criteria, $scope.year, $scope.selectedYearType.name);
        }
```

It should be `GetData` instead of `getData`.

```
function GetData(criteria, year, yearType) {
            var url = apiService.ApiUrl + "/Employees/EmployeeHistory/GetData/" + year + "/" + yearType;
            return apiService.DeferredPost(url, criteria);}
```

Comment: Even if service name is same it still fails

Comment: Can you post your apiService?

Comment: I have used `$scope.searchMethod.then(function (response)` instead of `$scope.searchMethod().then(function (response)`  still fails

Comment: You are using way too many things. What does this line do apiService.DeferredPost(url, criteria) ?

Comment: posted api service method

Comment: Again a typo apiService.DeferredPost but service function name is deferredPost

Comment: It's not typo its renamed as described in question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147949/discussion-between-vivz-and-user1030181).